# retrieve attribute value using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, attributes

I need to retrieve attribute value of `<div>` tag using jquery

This is my html code where `$_GET['availabel_table']` and `$_GET['number-of-person']` are coming from url

```
<div id=main_menu_data class="grid_21 alpha  prefix_1" availabel-table="<?php echo $_GET['availabel_table'] ?>" number-of-person="<?php echo $_GET['number_of_person'] ?>" >
```

Jquery code

```
var availabel_table = $("#main_menu_data").attr("availabel-table");
var number_of_person = $("#main_menu_data").attr("number-of-person");
```

but value is not coming in these variables. What i am doing wrong.

Comment: It's not valid HTML, should still work, but you should really be using data attributes.

Comment: Are you sure your values are there in the source?

Comment: It is spelled "available" FYI, would drive me nuts if I inherited that code :)

Comment: Try `data-availabel-table`

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
<div id=main_menu_data
```

should be this:

```
<div id="main_menu_data"
```

Comment: Yup, there's lot of incorrect HTML in there, must correct it to ensure that it's not the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Missing quotes on the DIV's id?

```
<div id="main_menu_data" class="grid_21 alpha  prefix_1" availabel-table="<?php echo  $_GET['availabel_table'] ?>" number-of-person="<?php echo $_GET['number_of_person'] ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your data values with with valid data attributes, your code would be something like:

```
  <div id="main_menu_data" class="grid_21 alpha  prefix_1" data-available-table="<?php echo     $_GET['availabel_table'] ?>" data-number-of-people="<?php echo $_GET['number_of_person'] ?>" >
```

then to access this data, you can use the jQuery data function:

```
  var available_table = $("#main_menu_data").data("available-table");
  var number_of_people = $("#main_menu_data").data("number-of-people");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var numberPerson= $('#number_of_person').val();
  var availabelTable= $('#availabel_table').val();
```

of course that you should be declare thats variables in html

Comment: val() will not return data attributes on a div element.